# How do I get my login function to work in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, authentication

I can't get my login def to work in my python/flask code

I have followed multiple tutorials on the internet but none of them works for me. The page does load the login screen but after that, it throws an error: 
*Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.*
When trying to switch things up and use different solutions the page keeps showing me the login page no matter what credentials you enter.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_user():
    if request.methods == "POST":
        if request.form['password'] == 'password' and request.form['username'] == 'username':
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('hello_world'))
        else:
            flash('wrong')
        return render_template("voorbeeld.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    my_var = session.get('logged_in', None)
    if my_var != True:
        return render_template("voorbeeld.html")
    else: 
        remainder of my code



<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>your title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
        <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="log in">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the login page to send the user back to the def hello_world and then follow the remainder of the code.

Comment: 1) always show full error message. 2) what do you have in template `voorbeeld.html` ? Maybe there is incorrect url. 3) you use `redirect(url_for('hello_world'))` - do you have `@app.route('/hello_world')` ? 4) you can always put some `print()` to display values in variables and display messages like `I'm inside "if request.methods"` and this way you can debug code.

Comment: 1) The full error message was stated in my post (I have put it in italics now) thats the error I get when filling in credentials and pressing the log in button.
2) I have added the HTML code of voorbeeld.html
3) I didnt know this was an error, should i just leave it blank so it refers to def hello_world?

Comment: I have solved my own problem already

Comment: By full error message, it means the full Traceback error.